# How to frame MySqlParamter with Linq SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, linq

How do/should i frame mysqlparameter?

Here are the ways i did it but nonetheless no output obtained from it :

```
var cities = ce.city.SqlQuery("Select * from world.city where Name like '%@p0%'", 
                 new MySqlParameter("@p0", kendoServerFilter.filter.Filters[0].Value))
                 .ToList();

var cities = ce.city.SqlQuery("Select * from world.city where Name like '%@p0%'", 
                 new MySqlParameter("p0", kendoServerFilter.filter.Filters[0].Value))
                 .ToList();

var cities = ce.city.SqlQuery("Select * from world.city where Name like @p0", 
                 new MySqlParameter("p0","'%" + kendoServerFilter.filter.Filters[0].Value + "%'"))
                 .ToList();
```

Statement works fine if i am building query by concatenating string but does not work when using parameterized query. Where am i going wrong? please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove single quote(`''`) from beginning and ending of `%` sign in parameter value

So your third query will be

```
var cities = ce.city.SqlQuery("Select * from world.city where Name LIKE @p0", 
                 new MySqlParameter("p0","%" + kendoServerFilter.filter.Filters[0].Value + "%"))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 'san' + '%'' at line 1' **(where san is my value)**

Comment: why do we need a + within the quoted string ? is it something related to mysql ? i am new to mysql environment

Comment: let me check it out :)

Comment: @MattBurner, i update my answer, view it carefully and remove that single quote from beginning and ending of `%` sign

Comment: Thanks this works.. also found out a way using string interpolation, sad to find out that table or column name cannot be parameterized.

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll try to find out by my way, if possible by you then upvote by clicking up arrow to my answer :)